# Counter but by specific number

Tags: javascript

so basically I am trying to create a counter that has a specific increments based on user input. If they say yes, it adds 3 to the counter, if no, then it adds 5. I'm not sure if I am simply being dumb or what... Currently, all that is happening is the counter value is being replaced by either the 3 or 5 and not being added to.

```
    <body>
        <div class="question">
            <script>
                function myFunction() {
                    var userAnswerRaw = document.getElementById("uAnswer").value;
                    var userAnswer = userAnswerRaw.toUpperCase();
                    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = userAnswer;

                    var counter = 0;

                    switch(String(userAnswer)){
                        case "YES":
                            counter+= 3;
                            document.getElementById("counterDisplay").innerHTML = counter;
                            break;
                        case "NO":
                            counter+= 5;
                            document.getElementById("counterDisplay").innerHTML = counter;
                            break;
                        default:
                            alert("You need to input either Yes or no!")
                            break;
                    }

                }
                </script>
            <h1>Questions</h1>
            <p id="test"></p>
            <p id="counterDisplay"></p>
            <button onclick="myFunction()">Click</button>
            <input type="text" id="uAnswer">
        </div>
    </body>
```

Any help, tips, and further readings are appreciated! Thanks!

Edit: Thanks much everyone, I just needed to add my variable up so it doesn't reset every time the function is run. Whooops!

Comment: please add the html part and event to the question.

Comment: I think your counter is defined in the scope of your function (set to 0 and incremented every event). You need to define it as a global variable. (set to 0 on initialization and incremented on every event)

Comment: Are you resetting the value of counter every time the code is executed?

Comment: Read it out loud. I call the funciton, it reads the input value, it sets it to uppercase, I set counter to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside needing of moving declaring and initializing `counter` outside of the function, you could change the style a little bit by using an object for the values and a simple check if the answer is valid.

BTW, `userAnswer` is already a string, so no more conversion is neccessary, because `value` returns always a string from a HTML `input` element.

```
const
    answers = { YES: 3, NO: 5 },
    userAnswer = document.getElementById("uAnswer").value.toUpperCase();

if (userAnswer in answers)  {
    counter += answers[userAnswer];
    document.getElementById("counterDisplay").innerHTML = counter;
} else {
    alert("You need to input either YES or NO!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have your counter initialization

```
var counter = 0;
```

right above the switch statement, then it will always start as `0` and just change to whatever scenario is happening. You need to move the initialization to a higher scope so that it doesn't get always reset to `0` before going into the switch.

Answer (score 0):

Your counter is initialized to zero so when you add three or five, it's going to be three or five.

Answer (score 0):

your `<script>` need to look like this with the counter outside the function

```
<script>
    var counter = 0;

    function myFunction() {
        var userAnswerRaw = document.getElementById("uAnswer").value;
        var userAnswer = userAnswerRaw.toUpperCase();
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = userAnswer;

        switch(String(userAnswer)){
            case "YES":
            counter+= 3;
            document.getElementById("counterDisplay").innerHTML = counter;
            break;
         case "NO":
            counter+= 5;
            document.getElementById("counterDisplay").innerHTML = counter;
            break;
        default:
            alert("You need to input either Yes or no!")
            break;
         }

     }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare your `counter` as a global variable, so when you increment it, it keeps its value.

Your function should be like this:

```
var counter = 0;
function myFunction() {
    let userAnswerRaw = document.getElementById("uAnswer").value;
    let userAnswer = userAnswerRaw.toUpperCase();
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = userAnswer;

    switch(String(userAnswer)){
        case "YES":
            counter+= 3;
            document.getElementById("counterDisplay").innerHTML = counter;
            break;
        case "NO":
            counter+= 5;
            document.getElementById("counterDisplay").innerHTML = counter;
            break;
        default:
            alert("You need to input either Yes or no!")
            break;
    }
}
```